# ClickOnceアプリケーションを起動する端末の.NET Frameworkをアプリ起動時にバージョンアップさせる方法を探しています。

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

## 概要

ClickOnceアプリケーションをユーザが更新する際、ユーザの端末内の.NET Frameworkが4.0以前のものであれば強制的に4.5以降のバージョンにアップデートする方法を探しています。

## 詳細

ClickOnceアプリケーションを発行し、ダウンロード専用サーバからダウンロードする際、下記のようなエラーがポップアップ出るようになりました。
※アプリを作成した.NetFrameworkのバージョンは4.5、ダウンロードしようとしたバージョンは3.5です。

```
Cannot continue. The application is improperly formatted.Contact the application vendor for assistance.
```

詳細を見ると次のようなエラーです。

```
ERROR SUMMARY
Exception reading manifest from https://hogehoge : the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
Manifest XML signature is not valid.
SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.
```

[こちらの記事](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826798/manifest-xml-signature-is-not-valid)を見たところ、これは.NET Frameworkの4.0から4.5へのバージョンアップの際、SHAの形式が変更されたことに起因していることがわかりました。

そのため、.NET Framework 4.5よりも前のバージョンがインストールされている端末でアプリの更新を行う際には.NET Framework 4.5を強制強制的にダウンロードするようにしたいと考えVisual Studioで次のような設定を行いました。

```
発行 -> 必須コンポーネントで下記にチェック。
・Microsoft.Net FrameWork 4.5（x86およびx64）
・Microsoft.Net FrameWork 4.5.1（x86およびx64）
・Microsoft.Net FrameWork 4.5.2（x86およびx64）
・Windowsインストーラ 4.5

発行 -> 更新で
・アプリケーションの更新を確認する　にチェック
・アプリケーションの更新を確認する方法を選択してください:
　アプリケーションの開始前に行う を選択
```

しかし、.NET Framework 3.5がインストールされている端末でアプリを更新しようとしても.NET Framework 4.5はインストールされず、エラーも元のままでした。

ClickOnceアプリケーションの必須コンポーネント設定に誤りがございますでしょうか？それともそもそもSHAの変更対応として適切ではないでしょうか？

ご教示よろしくお願いします。

## 動作環境

・.NET Frame Work 4.5
・.NET Frame Work 4.0以前
・Visual Studio2013

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/23100 マルチポスト